# NullPointerException when creating a 2-dimensional ArrayList in Java and JavaFX

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, dynamic-arrays

i want to code a "Four Wins"-Game with JavaFX, but when declaring the 2-dimensional TextField-Array "fields" and i want to print out the list-items, i get a NullPointerException, because there are not the TextField-Objects, but only null-Objects. Can someone help me with that?

```
@FXML Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7;
    @FXML TextField field00, field01, field02, field03, field04, field05,
              field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15,
              field20, field21, field22, field23, field24, field25,
              field30, field31, field32, field33, field34, field35,
              field40, field41, field42, field43, field44, field45,
              field50, field51, field52, field53, field54, field55,
              field60, field61, field62, field63, field64, field65;

    @FXML TextField[][] fields = {
            {field00, field01, field02, field03, field04, field05},
            {field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15},
            {field20, field21, field22, field23, field24, field25},
            {field30, field31, field32, field33, field34, field35},
            {field40, field41, field42, field43, field44, field45},
            {field50, field51, field52, field53, field54, field55},
            {field60, field61, field62, field63, field64, field65}
    };

    ArrayList<ArrayList<TextField>> freeFields = new ArrayList<>();

    private String player;
    private int turn = 1;

    public void initialize(){
        player();

        System.out.println(field00.getClass());
        for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
            ArrayList<TextField> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j = 0; j < fields[0].length; j++){
                arrayList.add(fields[i][j]);
            }
            freeFields.add(arrayList);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi & Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please provide the exact stack trace, but also try to make a clear, small reproducible snippet of code so that’s its easier to help you :) you may also want to have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get some pro tips

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side of

```
TextField[][] fields = {
        {field00, field01, field02, field03, field04, field05},
        {field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15},
        {field20, field21, field22, field23, field24, field25},
        {field30, field31, field32, field33, field34, field35},
        {field40, field41, field42, field43, field44, field45},
        {field50, field51, field52, field53, field54, field55},
        {field60, field61, field62, field63, field64, field65}
};
```

is evaluated during the object creation (in the initializer).

At this time none of the fields have been injected by `FXMLLoader` yet. If you want to fix this, move the initialisation of the field to the `initialize` method. This method is run by `FXMLLoader` after it injects all fields:

```
private TextField[][] fields;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    fields = ...;
}
```

---

I don't think it's a good idea to design this kind of GUI using SceneBuilder/fxml. You've got 42 = 7*6 `TextField` objects in the fxml and if you've got a typo in just a single `fx:id`, it breaks the code. It would be better/easier to maintain, if you use loops to create those `TextField`s and add them to the scene & data structure instead:

```
@FXML
private GridPane container; // inject a parent for TextFields here

private TextField[][] fields;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    fields = new TextField[7][6];
    for (int row = 0; row < fields.length; row++) {
        TextField[] fs = fields[row];
        for (int col = 0; col < fs.length; col++) {
            TextField f = new TextField();
            fs[col] = f;
            container.add(f, col, row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I also tried to make the TextFields in a loop, but then it looks like that: https://imgur.com/a/jY3vJNs

Comment: @DominikSchnell You may need to adjust the layout parameters of `GridPane`/add some column/row constraints in order for the `TextField`s to be aligned/sized properly for the loop approach to yield the desired outcome. I can't provide any more detailed info since I don't know the desired outcome...